# source code contacts android

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-source

I need to make my phone do something whenever the call button or the video call button is pressed. I've modified the dialpad and the calllog from the source code,and the call buttons there work the way i want them too. However, I've quite not been able to find out which .java file handles the call buttons from within the Contacts. Like, say, i click on Contacts and then select some contact and later in the next screen choose to press the call button.. Need to capture the onClick() here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know for sure. But the Contacts and Phone apps are tightly integrated, it might be that the Contacts app calls over into the Phone app when you select a specific contact.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe i'll need to look into it. As far as the dialpad and the callog go, it was in the Contacts app part itself and i could capture them from within. Even the swype part, i.e., from left-right for call and right-left for message when inside the contacts is also within the Contacts app. It is only the callbutton part which is quite hard to find out within.

Comment: Check "PhoneNumberInteraction" Class inside "com.android.contacts.interactions".